# circumventing cameras

Tags: detection

We have Samsung wired cameras placed in 9 different places in the home.  Somehow they are being circumvented and a laser doesn't seem to be the way it is happening as bright flashes do not appear on the video.  Clocks remain constant.  No way to shut off power until they are thru the door and then there is a locked generator that kicks in after a few seconds. Absolutely nothing shows up on the videos at slow speed, all appears normal.  How are they getting around the system and in the meantime, they are stealing like crazy!

Comment: how are they being circumvented?

Comment: Have you ruled out ghosts?  /sorry.  This isn't an InfoSec question unless your cameras are being compromised via some sort of network.  If you suspect that, we will need a lot more information to go on in order to help.

Comment: Who are "they" and why do you assume "they are stealing like crazy" during the time the camera footage was taken?

Comment: My friend, you've fallen for one of the classic blunders. (Only slight less famous is "Never get involved in a land war in Asia.")

They aren't bypassing your cameras. You never had whatever goods are being stolen- it is invoicing fraud.

Comment: Clocks should actually change a fair amount... otherwise you're looking at an image, not video.